# My Android AlertDialog is not moving up out of the way when the keyboard is shown

Tags: android, keyboard, alert, dialog

So I have a alert dialogue which I call from an activity when a button is pressed:

```
Button editLocation = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_trained_location_button);
    editLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showEditLocationDialog();
        }
    });


public void showEditLocationDialog(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AppTheme);
    builder.setTitle("Edit Location name");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_dialog, null));
    Window newLocationDialog = builder.show().getWindow();

    newLocationDialog.setLayout(DpToPxHelper.convertToPx(350, activity),
                                DpToPxHelper.convertToPx(175, activity));
    newLocationDialog.setDimAmount(.8f);
    newLocationDialog.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

}
```

Here is a the layout file.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <EditText
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:id="@+id/location_name_edit_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

(The buttons are defined in the builder, the layout only allows me to create an EditText field).

So my problem is when I bring up the keyboard to enter text into the EditText field the dialogue isn't pushed up so the buttons at the bottom are blocked:

[Before keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwjZM.png)

[After Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulqjB.png)

So what's weird is the text inside of the dialogue is pushed up...but the window isn't :(.

**What I've tried:**

1. `<android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`
   I've added that to the manifest.xml and observed that it still doesn't move     the dialogue box up.
2. `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>`
    I've tried this as well but it still has no affect.
3. `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`
    I've also tried that with no luck, the same behaviour happens the dialogue doesn't move up but the text inside gets pushed up.
4. Not trying anything (so no declaring in the manifest or .setSoftInputMode(...) ) I see the same behaviour so I don't think steps 1,2,3 have had any affect anyway.

So I've tried everything I could find on this site and I'm struggling to find a solution.  I feel the issue is related to the layout some how.

If anyone can help me find a solution that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it :D.

So the only problem was I was using the constructor builder(Activity..., Theme...).

Using the constructor builder(Activity...) (without theme) worked! I guess because it picks up the theme settings from that activity.

Comment: Adding to this answer as it seems to be the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49505073/352876), the important part is that the theme given to the builder shouldn't have a translucent status bar.