# Alert dialog not moving to up when keyboard is open in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

i have created one alert dialog in fragment dynamically.which has one edit text and one button.what my problem is when user focus on edit text keyboard is open and its hide dialog button.and my dialog is not moving to top.

```
private void AlertEditMode(final MyIshVo myIshVo) {
    final LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(getContext());
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(50,0,50,0);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(edittext);
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setView(linearLayout)
            .setTitle("Instant Share")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .create();


    // relativeLayout.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    edittext.setText(myIshVo.getMish_name());

    edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String ish_title = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
                    String instant_share_Id=myIshVo.getMinstant_share_Id();
                    if(ish_title==null || ish_title.equalsIgnoreCase("") || ish_title.contains("<") || ish_title.contains("\\") ){
                        //showToastMessage("Title should not be Empty");
                        edittext.setError("Please enter valid title.");
                    }else{
                        presenter.setEditIsh(ish_title,instant_share_Id);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
   // dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

}
```

i have already tried to give adjustresize to activity and dynamically give

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

but both solutions are not working.any other solutions please suggest thanks in advance.

[![check image][1]][1]

Comment: share your manifest file

Comment: this is my manifest code for activity <activity android:name=".activity.MainScreenActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            />

Comment: is it possible to attach the screen shot, of the UI.

Comment: `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` this will work

Comment: @Wizard i have changed to adjust pan but its not working

Comment: @war_Hero see screen shot

Comment: you need to write a custom layout and use it inside the alert dialog

Comment: that also i have tried ....but still custom layout  stay on center as u seen on screen shot.

Answer (score 16):

I've had this issue when the `Activity` in which the `AlertDialog` is shown had a translucent status bar theme.

So instead of initializing the builder with the classic `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` which uses the context's theme, I explicitly pass a dialog theme with no translucent status bar to it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar)
```

I picked this theme as it ensures compatibility with pre-lollipop devices, but other ones like `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog` should do the trick too.

Comment: the suggested theme seems to be what I wanted ... something basic and reliable. thanks

Comment: perfect solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm using MaterialComponents as my application's theme, so no solutions posted in here worked for me.

My real problem was that the AlertDialog was not resizing whenever the keyboard opened, so the alert was always behind the keyboard. Changing the soft input mode did the trick:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Example");

// set your custom view...

// Then show it
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

// This did the trick
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Yiu save my day dude 

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show dialog at the top then used below code..

```
    private void AlertEditMode(final MyIshVo myIshVo) {
    final LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(getContext());
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(50,0,50,0);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(edittext);
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setView(linearLayout)
            .setTitle("Instant Share")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .create();


    // relativeLayout.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    edittext.setText(myIshVo.getMish_name());

    edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String ish_title = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
                    String instant_share_Id=myIshVo.getMinstant_share_Id();
                    if(ish_title==null || ish_title.equalsIgnoreCase("") || ish_title.contains("<") || ish_title.contains("\\") ){
                        //showToastMessage("Title should not be Empty");
                        edittext.setError("Please enter valid title.");
                    }else{
                        presenter.setEditIsh(ish_title,instant_share_Id);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
    wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

    dialog.show();
    // dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer....its not probably what i was looking for....my problem is when i am opening keyboard ....dialog should be 
slide to top automatically.

Comment: that time used to edittext box setOnFocusChangeListener method and put dialog set up code according.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, try this way:

**Theme_Material_Dialog_Presentation**

```
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Presentation)
```